# backref class attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to initialize backrefs of mappers without some queries through a session? 
For example, I have two models, named "Client" and "Subject" in follow code:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = "clients"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    name = Column(String)

    subjects = relationship("Subject",  cascade="all,delete",
        backref=backref("client"))


class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subjects"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Client.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

Then, somewhere in my code, I want to get the backref `client` of the class `Subject` like this, but that raises an exception:

```
>>> Subject.client
AttributeError: type object 'Subject' has no attribute 'client'
```

After a query to `Client` like:

```
>>> session.query(Client).first()
>>> Subject.client
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x43ca1d0>
```

Attribute `client` was created after a query to the related model(mapper).
I don't want to make such "warming" queries!

Comment: Does declaring the backref as simply `backref='client'` work any better? I'm a little puzzled this doesn't work just normally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers

configure_mappers()
```

This has the advantage that it creates all the backrefs for all your models in one step.

Comment: I am surprised this is not spelled out more clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

Because SQLAlchemy uses metaclasses, the code that creates the back reference on the other class won't run until you have created at least *one* instance of the `Client` class.

The remedy is simple: create a `Client()` instance, and discard it again:

```
>>> Subject.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Subject' has no attribute 'client'
>>> Client()
<__main__.Client object at 0x104bdc690>
>>> Subject.client
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x104be9e10>
```

or use the [`configure_mappers`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers) utility function:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers
```

to scan your models for such references and initialize them. Creating any one instance calls this method under the hood, actually.

Comment: Where should I put the configure_mappers function call?

Comment: @user1111652: anywhere that is run after your models have been defined.

Comment: I put it right beneath the declaration of my model.py which defines all the models. Doesn't work

Comment: A little code sample would help me figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: @user1111652: "doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything. My code example would do exactly that; put it below the models. If you have multiple modules with models, make sure they are all imported first.

Comment: Still, when I initialize a child before the parent the backref is not an attribute of the child class, so I cannot set/access it.

Comment: @user1111652: Perhaps you could post a new question then, make sure to include an MCVE that demonstrates the issue clearly.

Comment: Ther you go, another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863993/sqlalchemy-backref-not-working-despite-configure-mappers