# Define backref parameter

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name_en = db.Column(db.String(100))
    user_country = db.relationship('User', backref='country')
    company_country = db.relationship('Company', backref='country')
```

In this example I am overriding the table name. So, what should be the backref? The `tablename` or the class name? Or can be anything else?

From the docs:

*backref is a simple way to also declare a new property on the xxxxx class*

So, the name of `backref` is only a general description?

And if I have two tables using the country table, i need to create two relationships, like in my example? the procedure is one relation by each reference in another table?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this example.

```
  class Parent(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'parent'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

  class Child(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'child'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

To store Child in Parent

Get parent object.

```
p = Parent.query.get(1)
```

Store in child object using backref

```
c = Child(parent=p)
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

To access parend through child object you will follow this.
Make object.

```
child = Child ()
```

Access through backref.

```
child.parent.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? This will make user.country into something like the model

```
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  country = db.relationship("Country", backref="users")

class Country(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'countries'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
  user_country = db.relationship("User")
```

Answer (score 0):

It does confused. Also sqlalchemy's doc is long and tedious, make it hard to understand.

> So, what should be the backref? The tablename or the class name? Or can be anything else?

Anything else can become the backref  name

> So, the name of backref is only a general description?

yes, it add a attribute in your class(in other words, table) dynamically.
Because SQLAlchemy uses metaclasses, the code that creates the back reference on the other class won't run until you have created at least one instance of the Client class.
See [backref-class-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921777/backref-class-attribute) for more details, such as access backref by `Subject.client` .

> And if I have two tables using the country table, i need to create two relationships, like in my example? the procedure is one relation by each reference in another table?

Sounds like you want a many to many relationship. Both the [association-table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) and [flask-doc](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#many-to-many-relationships) can help.

hope it helps :)