# SQLAlchemy backref not working despite configure_mappers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the following sample, there is an sqlalchemy model module:

```
meta = MetaData(naming_convention={
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
})


class Base(object):
    "Modify base to add standard columns across tables"
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())


class MixinLabel(object):
    label = Column(String, nullable=False)


Base = declarative_base(metadata=meta, cls=Base)


class Block(Base, MixinLabel):

    descendantId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('BlockGroup.id'))
    groupId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('BlockGroup.id'))

    position = Column(Integer)

    # one-to-one
    _descendant = relationship('BlockGroup',
                               cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                               single_parent=True,
                               foreign_keys=[descendantId],
                               backref=backref('_ascendant', uselist=False)
                               )


class BlockGroup(Base):
    "Abstract class"

    type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'blockgroup',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }

    # one-to-many
    children = relationship('Block',
                            cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                            backref=backref('group', uselist=False),
                            foreign_keys=[Block.groupId],
                            order_by='Block.position'
                            )
configure_mappers()
```

Notice the `configure_mappers()` call at the end. That one does not work. If I try to access the `Block.group` relation, I get an `AttributeError` exception raised:

```
AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'group'
```

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921777/backref-class-attribute/14921883?noredirect=1#comment80675037_14921883), `configure_mappers()` should resolve this. Somehow, `configure_mappers()` doesn't do its job. Something goes wrong.

Comment: It works for me after copy/pasting your code as written (along with the appropriate imports).  Have you tried running it in a fresh Python interpreter?  What version of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I use sqlalchemy 1.1.11.

Comment: Strange. I will strip my program down a bit. See where it goes wrong. I had to strip a lot of code to honour my nda and to make the post more compact. I guess the error in there somewhere

Comment: Notice that the error occurs only if you initialize a block, without initializing a blockgroup. when you set block.blockgroup, you get the error

Comment: You'd have to show how you are initializing a `Block`.

Comment: just use Block() to initialize the block. I use a subclass to initialize the group, in the same fashion. Then I set block.goup

Comment: Yeah, that works for me just fine :/

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue right now. Have you managed to resolve this somehow?